# Terraform for aws failing

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using terraform first time in order to create resources on my AWS account . I ran the below template for test but it always fails with the issue:

> Error parsing `<path>/main.tf`: At 1:10: illegal char

```
provider “aws” {
    access_key = “${var.access_key}”
    secret_key = “${var.access_secret_key}”
    region = “${var.region}”enter code here }
    resource "aws_vpc" "${var.vpc_name}" { cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16" enable_dns_hostnames = true }
```

> Error: terraform init There are some problems with the configuration, described below.

Comment: Edit your question to include both the code and the error.

Comment: Is your template using curly quotes? Can you [edit] the question to make the question match your template?

Comment: +1 to what @JasonAller said, try replacing all the `“smart quotes”` with `"straight quotes"` and see if the error persists

Comment: ...and indeed 1:10 would be a smart quote, so this looks like an error derived from a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead and let us know

```
provider "aws" {
   access_key = "${var.access_key}"
   secret_key = "${var.access_secret_key}"
   region     = "${var.region}" 
}
resource "aws_vpc" "${var.vpc_name}" { 
   cidr_block           = "10.0.0.0/16"
   enable_dns_hostnames = true
}
```